# Javascript ajax call don't have php response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax call but i can't see it. First in my front file i have the javascript:

```
someButton.addEventListener('click', function(){ makeRequest('arg') });
function makeRequest(params){

        var http_request = false,
            url = 'actions.php'+'?state='+params;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
                http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
            }
            }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
            try{
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){
                try{
                    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }catch(e){}
            }
        }

        if (!http_request) {
           console.log('Fail :( problem1');
           return false;
        }

        http_request.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
        http_request.open('GET', url, true);
        http_request.send(null);


        function alertContents(){

            if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
                if (http_request.status == 200) {

                    console.log(http_request.responseText);
                    console.log(http_request.responseXML);

                } else {
                    console.log('problem2.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in action.php i have:

```
<?php return 'bla'; ?>
```

The javascript ajax call is the commond code all can see searching in the web and the php is the most easiest i can put to prove. But it didn't works. 
In the console i don't have response and appear something like "the element isn't found".

if i execute the ajax with:

```
console.log(http_request);
```

it return:

```
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: alertContents(), readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "http://localhost/ordertask/task_act…", status: 200, statusText: "OK", responseType: "", response: "" }
```

Comment: Ok, the answer was easy and works perfectly with "echo" or "print", i don't know why i focus in the "return". Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Change you action.php to

```
<?php echo'bla'; ?>
```

Have a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php .I hope this helps.... This should work.

Comment: Also, just to be safe, remove `?>` from the end. It's a best practice. It prevents you from having accidential tailing waste characters. Ow, and please put a space between `echo` and `'bla'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php 
  echo'bla';
 exit;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the php file, instead of "return" statement try a print operation such as "print('bla');" or "echo 'bla';". Now when Ajax processes the returning message from php, at least should read "bla" and put it in the console.log().